# NSString isEqualToString not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

class define as following:

```
@interface KNBookmark : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *bookmarkId ;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *novelName ;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *novelId ;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *novelPic ;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *articleId ;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *articleTitle ;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *readRate ;
@end

@interface KNArticle : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *num ;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *articleId ;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title ;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *subject ;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *text ;
@end
```

The source code:

```
for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    KNArticle* article=[self.novel.articles objectAtIndex:i];

    NSLog(@"bookmark articleId='%@' articleId='%@'",self.bookmark.articleId,article.articleId);

    NSLog(@"bookmark articleId class='%@' articleId class='%@'",[self.bookmark.articleId class],[article.articleId class]);

    if([self.bookmark.articleId isEqualToString:article.articleId])
    {
        NSLog(@"equal");
        self.indexArticles=i;
        break;
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"not equal");
}
```

The NSLog output as following:

```
2014-07-16 22:56:14.768 novel[12685:90b] bookmark articleId='5680285' articleId='5680285'
2014-07-16 22:56:14.768 novel[12685:90b] bookmark articleId class='__NSCFString' articleId class='__NSCFNumber'
2014-07-16 22:56:14.769 novel[12685:90b] not equal
```

Why '5680295' not equal to '5680295"?
I have try the following code:

```
NSString* id1=@"5680295";
NSString* id2=@"5680295";
if([id1 isEqualToString:id2])
{
    NSLog(@"equal");
}
```

The above code show the "equal", but I still don't know why ?

Comment: There is a 5-second gap in those log lines.  Why is that?

Comment: @trojanfoe, it's probably just the OP stepping through the lines in the debugger.

Comment: i think its typecast issue maybe. can you match both that both are `NSString` or not using `isKindOfClass` like `if([article.articleId isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])`

Comment: Hmmm... is it possible that one `articleId` is an `NSNumber`?

Comment: What kind of class is `KNArticle`? what is it subclassed from?

Comment: How did you assign `article.articleId ` and `self.bookmark.articleId ` ?

Comment: Add `NSLog(@"%@", [article.articleId class]);` and tell us what you get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others pointed out, the reason why `isEqualToString:` returns `NO` is probably because `article.articleId` is not a string.

`self.bookmark.articleId` must be an instance of NSString because it responds to `isEqualToString:`

Make sure `articleId` is of the expected type:

```
NSAssert([article.articleId isKindOfClass:[NSString class]], @"bad type in articleId");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have update the problem. Both the article.articleId and self.bookmark.articleId are declared as the NSString, but the [article.articleId class] is the NSCFNumber. I would fix it. Thank you!